# I need a function to change any lower case letter typed in(and will only be one) into a list of strings

Tags: haskell

I need a function to change any lower case letter typed in(and will only be one) into a list of strings. Here is what I have so far:

```
letter :: char -> [String] 
letter a = (["AAA","A A"])
letter b = (["BBB","BBBB"])
```

When I type in 'b' it still give me the output of a i.e.

```
  letter 'b'
 ["AAA","A A"]
```

Why is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110098/i-nee-to-convert-lower-case-char-into-an-uppercase-list-string-in-haskell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues. GHC should have given you a warning about overlapping definitions for `letter`, which should tip you off:

`a` and `b` are *patterns*, not the characters `'a'` and `'b'`.

You need something more like:

```
letter :: Char -> [String] 
letter 'a' = ["AAA","A A"]
letter 'b' = ["BBB","BBBB"]
```

There are other options such as pattern guards or case statements, but simple pattern matching seems simplest here.

Also note the capitalization on `Char`. Types that start with a letter must be upper case.

Comment: Thanks @karakfa, I noticed that just a second before your comment.

Comment: yes I'm "trying" to use                                                                                                                    `up :: Char -> Char
      up x = chr ((ord x)- 32)` to change lower case into uppercase and use this as an auxiliary function to compensate for the capitalisation. How would I use the up function within this to do so?

Comment: also I'm getting this error: `Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : letter
*** Expected type : a -> [String]
*** Inferred type : Char -> [String]
`